# What permissions are required to upload to WWWRoot folder in ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created asp.net core 2.2 web API + MVC project and I am trying to upload a file to WWWRoot folder. I get access denied error when trying to upload file.

I would like to know appropriate accounts and required permissions to enable write access

I have applied UseStaticFiles in Startup file.

Here's code to upload file:

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Create(FileuploadRequest fileuploadRequest)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            else
            {

                if (fileuploadRequest.Logo.Length > 0)
                {
                    string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

                    var folderPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath,"Resources\\Images");

                    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(folderPath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        await fileuploadRequest.Logo.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

                    }
```

Comment: Facing similar issue, I am not able to upload file on debug mode also

Comment: does the folder exist wwwroot/Resources/Images? if not that is the reason for the error

Comment: also you need to append filename to folder path, ie it needs to be the path to the file not the folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Joe suggested ,make sure that the folder exists and try to append the fileName to your folder path like below:

```
 if (fileuploadRequest.Logo.Length > 0)
            {
                string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;

                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileuploadRequest.Logo.FileName);

                var folderPath = Path.Combine(webRootPath,"Resources\\Images",fileName);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(folderPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await fileuploadRequest.Logo.CopyToAsync(fileStream);

                }
```

Comment: thanks for explanation, filename was not appended - silly issue

Answer (score 0):

Using below of code work for me

```
public async Task<string> UploadAssets(IFormFile file, string fileName)
    {
        string storePath = "";
        try
        {
            storePath = Path.Combine(_assetSettings.Value.StorePath, $"{fileName}.{file.ContentType.Split("/")[1]}");
            using (var stream = new FileStream(storePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
         }
  }
```

Also try to run your Visual studio in Administrator right to allow full access to file, folder in your computer